# Filtro por período em vb

Tags: visual-basic-6

Criei um filtro por período em vb com o seguinte código:

```
Public Sub filtrar()
        Dim dtinicio As DateTime
        Dim dtfim As DateTime
        Dim tabela As New DataTable
        Dim strsql As String

        dtinicio = dtpInicio.Value.ToLongDateString
        dtfim = dtpFim.Value.ToLongDateString

        strsql = "SELECT RegistoEntradaSaida.Movimento, RegistoEntradaSaida.DataHora, Utente.Nome, Relação.Descrição AS Relação, Relacionado.Nome AS Visitante, RegistoEntradaSaida.CartãoID, RegistoEntradaSaida.DataHoraEntrada FROM ((RegistoEntradaSaida INNER JOIN Relação ON RegistoEntradaSaida.RelaçãoID = Relação.ID) INNER JOIN Relacionado ON RegistoEntradaSaida.RelacionadoID = Relacionado.ID) INNER JOIN Utente ON RegistoEntradaSaida.UtenteID = Utente.ID Where RegistoEntradaSaida.DataHora between @dtInicio And @dtFim And Utente.Nome Like @Nome ORDER BY RegistoEntradaSaida.DataHora DESC;"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Try

            CN.Open()
            cmd.Connection = CN
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtInicio", dtinicio)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtFim", dtfim)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", TextBox1.Text + "%")
            cmd.CommandText = strsql

            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                tabela.Load(reader)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = tabela
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Erro : " & ex.Message, "Consultar Registros")
        Finally
            CN.Close()
        End Try
        DataGridView1.Columns("DataHoraEntrada").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm"
    End Sub
```

A coluna `RegistoEntradaSaida.DataHora` que utilizo no `where` é `datetime`. O filtro funciona, mas tenho um pequeno problema, vou dar um exemplo:

- Se colocar data inicio = 17-10-2018 e data fim = 20-10-2018, no retorno dos dados da base de dados, retorna os dados de dia 17, como colocado na data inicio, mas só retorno os dados até ao dia 19, mas eu pretendia que fosse até ao dia 20 como coloquei na data fim. Retorna sempre um dia antes em relação ao dia que coloco na data fim.
  Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Tente formatar a data para realizar o filtro `@dtInicio` e `@dtFim` a maioria dos bancos mais populares possui suporte a função To_Date(data, 'dd/mm/yyyy').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi formatando a data da coluna que vem da base de dados e a variável `@dtInicio`, então foi só alterar a parte do `where` da `query` como mostro abaixo:

```
strsql = "...Where Format(RegistoEntradaSaida.DataHora, 'dd/mm/yyyy') between Format(@dtInicio, 'dd/mm/yyyy') And @dtFim ..."
```

Desta forma já retorna tudo desde o dia que seleciono na variável data inicio até ao dia que seleciono na variável da data fim.